# Jquery Mobile Jsonp from Listview to DetailsPage fiddle included

Tags: jquery, json, listview, mobile, dynamic

iam working on a Jquery Mobile Listview that gets Data CrossBrowsed Dynamicly from a .json File.

This Part works fine for me... now i want to display the DetailsPage from an Listview entry but cant get it working...

Need some help to get this working... my Brain stucks ...

Here is my JsFiddle

jsfiddle.net/masterluke/NbaZ6/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your transition to the Details page is working correctly but you're not sure how to populate the page with the data from the listview.

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rfF3j/1/

When it's rendering the data it does a few things differently:

1. It stashes all the data in the `dataStore` object, keyed by `item.id`.
2. It attaches the item.id to the newly created row by using the `.jqmData` function.
3. Creates a click handler on the row that, when clicked:

   1. Gets the `item-id` from the row.
   2. Uses that to find the `item` from `dataStore`.
   3. Populates the Details page with the `item` data.

Given, this isn't the best way to store your data but it's an example of the fact that you'll want to keep it around somewhere so you can reuse it later.

Comment: Wow this helped me alot! But i have another Problem... On my first Page index.html i have a list of categorys on my second Page restaurants.html i have your modified Code to list all Companys for specified Category ( Multipagetemplate). It looks lke that Jquery Mobile Kills something, because the List doesn't loading on Iphone in Fullscreen.. Did i have to make something like mobilechangePage or what?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Is the javascript not running on the Companies page?  If that's the case, it may have to do with the ajax navigation which doesn't run incoming js.  You'd want to move all the javascript into another file that's included on every page and then call it on one of the page change/show events.

Answer (score 0):

Ohhh sorry for my stupid Question ( my Brain was Codefrozen), i solved my problem with ajax="false" but this was not the best Solution for me but its Ok for this small WebApp...

I have also another Question to you or others about Jsonp!
I want to filter Results by Category "Objects" and Display the Arrays in Listviews only for Specified Categorys on Link click
Here is my JsonP file ...

[Full JsonPCode on Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/masterluke/2M9LN/)

```
        "id":"4",
    "name":"Marilyn",
    "slogan":"Essen&Trinken",
    "beschreibung":"diverse Leckereien in Verbindung mit einem in Einzelbrühung hergestellten Kaffee",
    "images":["http://bistro.de/427428_363474813673251_1907009930_n.jpg"],
    "offen1":"Di-So ab 11 Uhr",
    "offen2":"Montag Ruhetag",
    "offen3":"",
    "homepage":"http://",
    "strasse":"Am Markt 36",
    "ort":"hometown",
    "telefon":"tel: 1234242888193",
    "google":"http://.de"
}
```